# Showing sql data in HTML table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm very, very new to HTML, PHP and SQL, so this question might sound less than clever, but the situation is starting to annoy me.

I want to display data from my Mysql-database named "movies" in an HTML-table on my website. The table is named "test". I understand that I need php to process the query from sql to html.

However, and I've read a lot of answers/tutorials both here and elsewhere, I can't get my code to work.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db('movies');

$query = "SELECT * FROM test";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td></tr>"; 
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close();

?>
```

To make it as simple as possible for me, the table contains only two entries with only and ID and a name.

This is what displays when I open the website in html-format in Chrome:

"; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "" . $row['Name'] . ""; } echo ""; mysql_close(); ?>

I can't figure out where the problem lies, so now I turn to here. If my goal is to display the two entries from my table in a table on my website, where do I need to fix what in my code?

Is it simply because I can't open the file anymore in Chrome, when I have php-code included? If so, what program would I need to open the file in?

Thanks for your time and hopefully a little help!

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with a confused stew of concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: If you just open the file from your local filesystem with Chrome, it won't execute any of the PHP code. The file needs to be loaded from a web server that is configured to process files with PHP.

Comment: if you see the php code, you dont have or are not using a webserver with php enabled. you cant juat open the file, it has to be serve red via a server

Comment: Don't panic / Smith: if I understand correctly, I would need something like XAMPP when opening the file in order to execute the PHP correctly? And only stick to Chrome when dealing with Html? Funny how tutorials doesn't seem to mention that. But will  install as soon as work ends, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `mysqli_query($connection, $query)` instead of `mysql_query($query)` and  `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` instead of  `mysql_fetch_array($result)`.

Notice the `$connection` variable which is necessary with the new `mysqli`.

You also need to use the new mysqli_connect. For example, try,

$connection = mysqli_connect( 'localhost,  'root', 'password', 'movies');

I assume 'test' is a table in the 'movie' database.

Comment: I am trying to replicate, so that I can accept the answer, but it seems that php and mysql in their newest versions have trouble connecting. Trying to fix that first :/

Comment: You also need to use the new mysqli_connect. For example, try,

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser =  'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'movies'';

 $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

This will define the $connection variable.

Comment: Thank you! It took a few hours, a re-install of Mysql Workbench (plus a few strange error-messages), but it works now!